# protected variables and php __get method

Tags: php, get, visibility

I am a new learner of PHP. I really need help. Caa you see what is the difference here between __get method and getcount() method. I think they both do the same thing, but I wonder if there is an issue about visibility or something. I am sharing the code. Thanks a lott!

```
protected $count = null;
protected $max = null;

public function getCount(){
    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from ogrenci");
    $count = mysql_ results($rs, 0, 0);
    mysql_free_result($rs);
}

public function __get($name) {
    if($name == 'count') {
        if($this->count == null) {
            $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from ogrenci");
            $count = mysql_ results($rs, 0, 0);
            mysql_free_result($rs);
        }
    return $this->count;
    }
    else if ($name == 'max')
    {
        //some code
    }
}
}
$o=new Ogrenci();
echo $o->count;
echo $o->getCount();
```

Comment: you never save/return `$count` anywhere, so it's just a local variable that's destroyed when the method returns.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `getCount()` you aren't setting anything.  Also you aren't returning anything so it doesn't echo anything.
2. In `__get()` you are returning `$this->count` but you haven't set it anywhere, so presumably it doesn't echo anything.

Maybe somewhere you want:

```
$this->count = mysql_results($rs, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while writing the code. It is $this->count = mysql_results($rs, 0, 0); in the second method. Now they return exactly the same thing. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `getCount()` is a custom dedicated method to count from `ogrenci`.

`__get()` belongs to the family of «magic methods», it is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

You can read more information about magic method in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

You should not use `__get` to count something in PHP, you should keep `getCount` method.